# Get video from BLOB and play that video using struts2 action using <iframe> or <embed> tag

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, video-streaming

I can successfully open a video read from a BLOB by using `<s:url action='downappsuservideo'/>`, but it doesn't work when I put it in an embed tag.

How to play it inside the page ?

```xml
        <embed src="<s:url action='downappsuservideo'/>" 
              type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
       pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 
              name="mediaplayer1" 
     ShowStatusBar="true" 
 EnableContextMenu="false" 
             width="700" 
            height="500" 
         autostart="false" 
              loop="false" 
             align="middle" 
            volume="60">
        </embed>
```

Comment: BLOB is database object type used to store binary information to the table.

Comment: Above url action is not working for me but when i used  only  (<s:url  action='downappsuservideo'/>) its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an iframe nor an embed tag. Just use [HTML5 `<video>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) that is the new, standard way:

```xml
<video src = "<s:url action='downappsuservideo'/>" 
  autoplay = "false"
     width = "700" 
    height = "500" 
      loop = "false" 
    poster = "posterimage.jpg">

  Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos, 
  but don't worry, you can <a href="<s:url action='downappsuservideo'/>">download it</a>
  and watch it with your favorite video player!

</video>
```

Comment: Thanks(Andrew Ligios)